# Прошу помощи в написании кода библиотека pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть вот такой фрагмент кода:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "1п":
            markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ("Подписаться", url = "(Условно ссылка)")
            markup1.add (item1)
            bot.send_message (call.message.chat.id, "Подпишись", reply_markup=markup1)
```

Что написать дальше, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку **Подписаться** (*inline кнопка, прикреплённая к сообщению*) бот отправлял сообщение.

Comment: Курите мануал. (документацию)

Comment: @kotleni подобные рекомендации слишком размыты. Стоит от них воздерживаться )

Comment: @Kromster, это самый точный ответ на вопрос. :)

Answer (score 0):

У каждой кнопки есть своя callback-data, отслеживайте это событие.

```
item = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка", callback_data = 'testovaya_data')

if call.data == 'testovaya_data':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы нажали на кнопку")
```